# How to determine array type based on signature

Tags: java

Based on just looking at the signature, how do you determine if an array is most likely perfect sized or oversized?
I know perfect sized arrays are used when the size of the array is known, otherwise an oversized array is used, but I don’t know how to determine (by looking at it) the array type based on a signature.

For example: `public static void myMethod(int[] ray, int size)`
Or: `public static myMethod(int[] ray, boolean value)`

Comment: If `ray.length == size` then the `ray` array is perfect-sized, if `size < ray.length` then the `ray` array is oversized, and if `size > ray.length` then the array is undersized. I mean, isn't that the definition of the words, so why do you ask? --- Since the second method doesn't specify a parameter indicating that array is only partially used, the method by definition expects a perfect-sized array. --- Your question doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @Andreas we don’t know any sizes, so how can we tell?

Comment: What do you mean *"we don’t know any sizes"*? Java arrays has a fixed size, so we *know* the size (aka `length`) of the array. The parameter `size` would also specify a value that we now *know*. Perhaps you should (re)read the section about arrays in your Java learning material, if you don't think we know the size of an array at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I see your confusion.

Java array *declarations* never specify a size. An array variable can always be assigned arrays of different length.

Actual arrays at *runtime* will always have a fixed size, and the array itself know what that size is (the `length` field).

Java (the language) doesn't have the concept of perfect-sized or oversized arrays. That is only a concept for how the array is *used*.

Since an array knows it's own size at runtime, there is never a need to explicitly specify the size. A method that explicitly requires a size can work with over-sized arrays, because the explicit size parameter can be used to only process part of the array.

So, `myMethod(int[] ray, int size)` is a method that can work with oversized arrays.

`myMethod(int[] ray, boolean value)` can only work with perfect-sized arrays, because there is no way to detect partial usage of the array.